# SQL filter on unknown number of columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, relational-division

I have table containing products, a table containing tags for the products where each product can have several tags, eg

```
products

product_id|name|…
1         |book
2         |game
3         |desk
…
```

,

```
tags

product_id|tag
3         |used
3         |physical
```

Is there a “nice” way using only SQL to query for all products which have all given tags  where the tags are in an array only known at compile time?

The only way I can think of is programmatically generating a query with multiple `JOIN`s on `tags`, renaming to `tag1`, `tag2` and so on and then filtering in the `WHERE` clause with `tag1 = tags_array[1] AND tag2 = tags_array[2]` and so on.

I am using SQLITE, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given list of tags, you can use relational division. Say we want the ids of all products that have both tags `'used'` and `'physical'`

```
select product_id
from tags
where tag in ('used', 'physical')     -- either one tag or the other
group by product_id                     
having count(*) = 2                     -- both are available for this product
```

If you are going to parameterized this query, you just need to:

- programmatically generate the list of products in the `in` clause (the number of wanted tags is variable, which affects the query string)
- pass the count of parameter to the `having` clause

Note that SQLite does not support arrays out of the box.

If you want the product name as well, we can join with `products`:

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
inner join tags t on t.product_id = p.product_id
where t.tag in ('used', 'physical')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and a **subquery**:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN tags t ON p.product_id = t.product_id
WHERE t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on an array of tags to easily count its length, which can then be used in the having clause.

```
select t.product_id, max(p.name)
from products p
inner join tags t on t.product_id = p.product_id
inner join (
  SELECT value as tag 
  FROM json_each('["used", "physical"]')
) as s on s.tag = t.tag
group by t.product_id
having count(*) = json_array_length('["used", "physical"]');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T4dISf7Z)